# Get 1st column values on .csv file on python

Tags: python, csv

i am newbie at python programming, 
i have a .csv file containing mac address and signal strength data from an AP
consider my csv data is:

[image: My csv data]

i want to get just mac address values which is the 1st row, referring to https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html
i already tried

```
import csv
import json

with open('DataFTrainBarucp.csv') as csvfile:
    ader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in ader:
        print row[0]
```

but it will print the first column from my csv, how to get 1st row data, please help

Comment: could you please paste your input here in stackoverflow and show what you tried ?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials. Using [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#reader-objects) you could go through the file, getting a list representing each row in the file, and appending the first item to another list

Comment: @roganjosh i already tried it, but what i want is to get just 1st column values, not row

Comment: Then you need to include what you tried. This is easily solved. When you read a `.csv` this effectively gives you back a nested list. You have to iterate that list somehow.

Comment: @nexus66 i already tried everything from the website, the result is they print every values on my csv file, what i want is get 1st column from my csv file

Comment: @roganjoshi already edited it

Comment: Your code seems to work fine. Are you getting columns and rows confused?

Comment: Wait a second... are you sure you're using "row" and "column" correctly? Do you actually want the first _row_ (now we can see the data)?

Comment: omg, hahaha i am so sorry, i just realized it. I want to get just mac address which is first row, and my code print the first column lol @JamoBox thanks sir, it works wonderully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine for columns. Maybe you meant that you want to print the row (i.e the MAC address headers)?

Here is the solution for each:

First Row:

```
print([x for x in csv.reader(csvfile)][0])
```

First Column:

```
print([x[0] for x in csv.reader(csvfile)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use `csv`? The `pandas` package has easy to use file reading functions with a usecols option. Try something like:

```
import pandas as pd
my_data = pd.read_csv('my_data_file', sep=',', header=0, usecols=[0])
```

`numpy` file reading functions also have a columns option.

Comment: @M.AgusTriMulyono Try now. Also, are you sure the delimiter is a comma? That might be the issue with your first attempt as well.

Comment: I think there's a confusion between `row` and `column` here. Your answer is valid for the question as-was, but now I'm not so sure. Welcome to Stack Overflow? :P